# Hibernate, one UserType with different number of columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I have class

`class DateOptTimeType implements org.hibernate.usertype.UserType`

that works with two columns

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "com.mmyPack.DateOptTimeType")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Columns(columns = {
                 @javax.persistence.Column(name = "DATE1"),
                 @javax.persistence.Column(name = "FLAG")
                                   }) protected DateOptTime dateOfDeath;
```

Can i do, that class will work with 1 column too (with 1 column and with two columns), like

```
                    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "DATE1"),
                    protected DateOptTime dateOfDeath;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 2 UserTypes because the UserType returns the number of needed columns in `getSqlTypes()`